# Grails Run-app exception "ClassNotFoundException: net.sf.json.JSONObject"

Tags: grails, json-lib

I am getting the above exception when i do run-app on my grails application

```
[java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: net.sf.json.JSONObject
,   at org.codehaus.groovy.tools.RootLoader.findClass(RootLoader.java:156)
,   at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)
,   at org.codehaus.groovy.tools.RootLoader.loadClass(RootLoader.java:128)
,   at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
,   at groovyx.net.http.HTTPBuilder.(HTTPBuilder.java:175)
,   at com.cm.admanager.adapter.GWebServiceRequest.getXml(GWebServiceRequest.groovy:60)
,   at com.cm.admanager.adapter.GWebServiceRequest$getXml$0.callStatic(Unknown Source)
,   at com.cm.admanager.adapter.GWebServiceRequest.getXml(GWebServiceRequest.groovy:49)
,   at com.cm.admanager.adapter.GWebServiceRequest$getXml.call(Unknown Source)
,   at com.cm.admanager.parser.BaseParser.getWebServiceResultsParsed(BaseParser.groovy:64)
,   at com.cm.admanager.parser.BaseParser$getWebServiceResultsParsed.call(Unknown Source)
,   at nna.autodata.parser.AutodataResultParser.getWebServiceResultsParsed(AutodataResultParser.groovy:530)
,   at nna.autodata.parser.AutodataResultParser$getWebServiceResultsParsed.callCurrent(Unknown Source)
,   at nna.autodata.parser.AutodataResultParser.parseModelLines(AutodataResultParser.groovy:131)
,   at nna.autodata.parser.AutodataResultParser$parseModelLines.call(Unknown Source)
,   at nna.autodata.AutodataService.getModelLines(AutodataService.groovy:58)
,   at nna.autodata.AutodataService$getModelLines.call(Unknown Source)
,   at nna.autodata.AutodataService$getModelLines.call(Unknown Source)
,   at nna.shoppingtools.adapter.StModelLineDataService.getModelLines(StModelLineDataService.groovy:62)
,   at nna.shoppingtools.adapter.StModelLineDataService$getModelLines.call(Unknown Source)
,   at nna.shoppingtools.adapter.StModelLineDataService$getModelLines.call(Unknown Source)
,   at nna.shoppingtools.vehicle.StActiveModelLineService.fetchAutodataModelLines(StActiveModelLineService.groovy:257)
,   at nna.shoppingtools.vehicle.StActiveModelLineService.cacheAllActiveModelLinesWithNoMarketingData(StActiveModelLineService.groovy:207)
,   at nna.shoppingtools.vehicle.StActiveModelLineService$$FastClassByCGLIB$$c14200c9.invoke()
,   at net.sf.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:149)
,   at org.aspectj.lang.ProceedingJoinPoint$proceed.call(Unknown Source)
,   at cm.springcache.CMCachingAspect$_invokeCachedMethod_closure1.doCall(CMCachingAspect.groovy:31)
,   at cm.springcache.CMCachingAspect$_invokeCachedMethod_closure1.doCall(CMCachingAspect.groovy)
,   at grails.plugin.springcache.SpringcacheService.doWithCacheInternal(SpringcacheService.groovy:155)
,   at grails.plugin.springcache.SpringcacheService.this$2$doWithCacheInternal(SpringcacheService.groovy)
,   at grails.plugin.springcache.SpringcacheService$this$2$doWithCacheInternal.callCurrent(Unknown Source)
,   at grails.plugin.springcache.SpringcacheService.doWithCache(SpringcacheService.groovy:84)
,   at grails.plugin.springcache.SpringcacheService$doWithCache.call(Unknown Source)
,   at cm.springcache.CMCachingAspect.invokeCachedMethod(CMCachingAspect.groovy:30)
,   at nci.nissan.shoppingtools.vehicle.StActiveModelLineService$$EnhancerByCGLIB$$f8b20934.cacheAllActiveModelLinesWithNoMarketingData()
,   at nna.shoppingtools.vehicle.StActiveModelLineService$cacheAllActiveModelLinesWithNoMarketingData.call(Unknown Source)
,   at nna.shoppingtools.vehicle.StActiveModelLineService$cacheAllActiveModelLinesWithNoMarketingData.call(Unknown Source)
,   at nna.shoppingtools.vehicle.StActiveModelLineService.getAllActiveModelLinesWithNoMarketingData(StActiveModelLineService.groovy:196)
,   at nna.shoppingtools.vehicle.StActiveModelLineService$getAllActiveModelLinesWithNoMarketingData.callCurrent(Unknown Source)
,   at nna.shoppingtools.vehicle.StActiveModelLineService$getAllActiveModelLinesWithNoMarketingData.callCurrent(Unknown Source)
,   at nna.shoppingtools.vehicle.StActiveModelLineService.cacheAllActiveModelLines(StActiveModelLineService.groovy:180)
,   at nna.shoppingtools.vehicle.StActiveModelLineService$$FastClassByCGLIB$$c14200c9.invoke()
,   at net.sf.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:149)
,   at org.aspectj.lang.ProceedingJoinPoint$proceed.call(Unknown Source)
,   at cm.springcache.CMCachingAspect$_invokeCachedMethod_closure1.doCall(CMCachingAspect.groovy:31)
,   at cm.springcache.CMCachingAspect$_invokeCachedMethod_closure1.doCall(CMCachingAspect.groovy)
,   at grails.plugin.springcache.SpringcacheService.doWithCacheInternal(SpringcacheService.groovy:155)
,   at grails.plugin.springcache.SpringcacheService.this$2$doWithCacheInternal(SpringcacheService.groovy)
,   at grails.plugin.springcache.SpringcacheService$this$2$doWithCacheInternal.callCurrent(Unknown Source)
,   at grails.plugin.springcache.SpringcacheService.doWithCache(SpringcacheService.groovy:84)
,   at grails.plugin.springcache.SpringcacheService$doWithCache.call(Unknown Source)
,   at cm.springcache.CMCachingAspect.invokeCachedMethod(CMCachingAspect.groovy:30)
,   at nci.nissan.shoppingtools.vehicle.StActiveModelLineService$$EnhancerByCGLIB$$f8b20934.cacheAllActiveModelLines()
,   at nna.shoppingtools.vehicle.StActiveModelLineService$cacheAllActiveModelLines.call(Unknown Source)
,   at nna.shoppingtools.vehicle.StActiveModelLineService$cacheAllActiveModelLines.call(Unknown Source)
,   at nna.shoppingtools.vehicle.StActiveModelLineService.getAllActiveModelLines(StActiveModelLineService.groovy:166)
,   at nna.shoppingtools.vehicle.StActiveModelLineService$getAllActiveModelLines.callCurrent(Unknown Source)
,   at nna.shoppingtools.vehicle.StActiveModelLineService$getAllActiveModelLines.callCurrent(Unknown Source)
,   at nna.shoppingtools.vehicle.StActiveModelLineService.getActiveModelLines(StActiveModelLineService.groovy:44)
,   at nna.shoppingtools.vehicle.StActiveModelLineService$$FastClassByCGLIB$$c14200c9.invoke()
,   at net.sf.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:149)
,   at nci.nissan.shoppingtools.vehicle.StActiveModelLineService$$EnhancerByCGLIB$$f8b20934.getActiveModelLines()
,   at nna.shoppingtools.vehicle.StActiveModelLineService$getActiveModelLines.call(Unknown Source)
,   at nna.shoppingtools.vehicle.StActiveModelLineService$getActiveModelLines.call(Unknown Source)
,   at com.cm.shoppingtools.service.core.ModelLineService.getConfigurableModelLines(ModelLineService.groovy:155)
,   at com.cm.shoppingtools.service.core.ModelLineService$$FastClassByCGLIB$$abffaa9c.invoke()
,   at net.sf.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:149)
,   at com.cm.shoppingtools.service.core.ModelLineService$$EnhancerByCGLIB$$63de0fb0.getConfigurableModelLines()
,   at com.cm.shoppingtools.service.core.ModelLineService$getConfigurableModelLines.call(Unknown Source)
,   at com.cm.shoppingtools.service.core.ModelLineService$getConfigurableModelLines.call(Unknown Source)
,   at com.cm.shoppingtools.controller.core.ModelLineController$_closure1.doCall(ModelLineController.groovy:45)
,   at com.cm.shoppingtools.controller.core.ModelLineController$_closure1.doCall(ModelLineController.groovy)
,   at grails.plugin.springcache.web.GrailsFragmentCachingFilter.doFilter(GrailsFragmentCachingFilter.groovy:66)
,   at net.sf.ehcache.constructs.web.filter.Filter.doFilter(Filter.java:86)
,   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:695)
]
```

The point to note is that app runs and I get the website link, but when I try and access the website on my browser, that's when everything breaks and I get this exception.

My BuildConfig.groovy has the following dependencies

```
dependencies {
    compile('org.hibernate:hibernate-jmx:3.3.1.GA') {
        excludes 'hibernate-core', 'log4j', 'slf4j-log4j12'
    }
    compile('com.google.guava:guava:16.0.1') { // guava:16.0. required for JBoss 7 
        transitive = false
    }
    compile('net.sf.json-lib:json-lib:jar:2.3')
    runtime 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpcore:4.4.1'
}
```

This is the project I was given at my new job. I have not written this code and the person who did has left the company.

Thanks

Comment: Could you show a piece of code that causes this error?

Comment: Which version of grails?

Comment: Grails version 1.3.7

Comment: Call `grails dependency-report` and check which version of `json-lib` is used. Your version may be overriden by internal dependencies or other elements

Answer (score 2):

I guess there is problem with the version of json-lib you are using. Try adding below to

`BuildConfig.groovy`

```
compile 'net.sf.json-lib:json-lib:2.4'
```

Notice you dependency which is `compile('net.sf.json-lib:json-lib:jar:2.3')`. It should be rather `compile('net.sf.json-lib:json-lib:2.3')`.
I would say try with latest version as you would get new features and bugs fixed in that.

Comment: So I tried that. When using 2.4, I got a different imx jar error. The project didn't even compile. While using 2.3, I got the following error:   Compile error during compilation with javac.
error: error reading /Users/ritwickg/.ivy2/cache/net.sf.json-lib/json-lib/jars/json-lib-2.3.jar; cannot read zip file
1 error '

Comment: Hmm! try grails clean-all. Seems old jar has not been deleted by grails.

Comment: I am using grails version 1.3.7. Don't think it has clean-all. Got this:  Resolving dependencies...
Dependencies resolved in 459ms.
Running pre-compiled script
Script 'CleanAll' not found, did you mean:
   1) Clean
   2) ClearProxy_
   3) CreateController
   4) CreateApp_
   5) ReleasePlugin
Please make a selection or enter Q to quit: q

Answer (score 0):

I resolved it. I had to delete the .grails and .ivy2 folder and recompile again. It downloaded all the correct dependencies and worked. Thanks a lot for help guys

Comment: that was a clean-all actually ;)